# Get sum of values between multiple date ranges

Tags: sql

I have a following table. I want to sum of values which is between two dates year by year.

| Date | Point |
| --- | --- |
| 24.11.2016 | 10 |
| 27.10.2016 | 20 |
| 12.10.2018 | 35 |
| 19.03.2018 | 50 |
| 15.11.2017 | 10 |
| 25.06.2020 | 15 |
| 09.12.2019 | 10 |

The dates' range should be two date variable which have same day and month for example (12.10.2016-12.10.2021). I want to see sum of values like 12.10.2016 - 12.10.2017 , 12.10.2017 - 12.10.2018...

So result should be like :

| Date | Point |
| --- | --- |
| 12.10.2016 - 12.10.2017 | 30 |
| 12.10.2017 - 12.10.2018 | 60 |
| 12.10.2018 - 12.10.2019 | 35 |
| 12.10.2019 - 12.10.2020 | 25 |

Date column does not have to seen like. Important point is get correct sum values.

Is there any way to do with a simple function, query, or view.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and it won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to shout at us when you're asking us for free help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your SQL tagged, so here is an answer for MySQL.
To just get the sum between two date values, you could run a query like this:

```
select sum(point) from foo
where date between '2016-10-12' and '2017-10-11';
select sum(point) from foo
where date between '2017-10-12' and '2018-10-11';
select sum(point) from foo
where date between '2018-10-12' and '2019-10-11';
select sum(point) from foo
where date between '2019-10-12' and '2020-10-11';
```

Between is inclusive, so I changed the second date to 20xx-10-11 based off your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

you can use where or as follow

```
select sum(point) from foo
where (date between '2016-10-12' and '2017-10-11')
or (date between '2017-10-12' and '2018-10-11');
```